# How do I make a program recognize whether to use A or An based on the variable the user inputs?

Tags: python, string, variables, input, output

This is my second day using Python. I'm using Visual Studios Code with Python 3.
I'm trying to make a madlib program in python. I'm having trouble with figuring out how to have the program automatically recognize whether to use a or an based on the variable they entered when I asked. For now I just have a(n) to be safe but I don't know how to just have it recognize that if they input the word apple then the program should say "an apple" or if they put grape then it should say "a grape"

```
print(timemin, "minutes later.",capitalize_string, "used a(n)", noun1, "to luer it outside.")
```

```
print("Suddenly, a(n)", animal2, "raced towards us and caused ")
```

capitalize_string, animal2, timein, noun1 are all variables.

I tried googling my problem but have not been able to find any help. I just want to learn how to make my program automatically recognize if the variable needs an (a or an) so that when the madlib prints out, it doesn't say "Jeff saw a(n) apple" but instead says "Jeff saw an apple" because the program recognized the variable started with a vowel.

Comment: How would you determine whether to use "a" or "an" without Python?

Comment: I have no idea. But I need my madlib to read out smoothly and automatically put the right "a" or "an" before the variable in the output based on if the user typed a word that started with a vowel or consonant.

Comment: If you want to write a program which does something, you should first know what you want it to do. If you don't know when a or an is right, there is no way you are going to put it in code.

Comment: @zvone I know when they need that but I don't know how to make the program know that. It's based on what the user will put in as the answers for variables when I prompt them to type in for example, an animal. I need the program to automatically know that if they type ape, it needs an, if they type bat, it needs a. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: This is an example of the output: Please enter the following:

adjective: happy
animal: zebra
verb: sneeze
exclamation: hooray
verb: read
verb: drive

Your story is:

The other day, I was really in trouble. It all started when I saw a very
happy zebra sneeze down the hallway. "Hooray!" I yelled. But all
I could think to do was to read over and over. Miraculously,
that caused it to stop, but not before it tried to drive
right in front of my family.                                                                                     So it needs to recognize what the user inputs

Comment: The main problem I see is knowing which article goes with a word. That depends on pronunciation of the word, rather than on the characters. So, you need to find out whether the word is pronounced starting with a vowel. If you know how to define which words are pronounced that way, the rest is easy. And that is not a programming problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I just convert the name to all lowercase, then check if the first letter is a vowel and doesen't start with "eu", "ur", "uni". There is also an exeption when the word starts with an unaspirated H, but it is extremely rare in English. The four words "hour", "honest", "honor", "herb" and their variations "honestly", "honorable", "herbalist", etc. represent all the words in English that use an unaspirated H.

```
def add_article(word):
    # Source for the checker: https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/indefinite-article/
    VOWELS = "aeiou"
    EXEMPTIONS = ("hour", "honest", "honor", "herb")
    l_word = word.lower()
    if (l_word[0] in VOWELS and not l_word.startswith(("eu", "ur", "uni"))) or l_word.startswith(EXEMPTIONS):
        article = "an"
    else:
        article = "a"
    return f"{article} {word}"


animal = input("Please enter an animal name: ")
print(f"Suddenly, {add_article(animal)} raced towards us and caused...")
```

Example output:

```
Please enter an animal name: dog
Suddenly, a dog raced towards us and caused...
```

```
Please enter an animal name: owl
Suddenly, an owl raced towards us and caused...
```

Comment: Exception: "A horse", but "an hour" or "an honest attempt".  Welcome to English 

Comment: Is there a way to apply that rule to all the variables that they enter? Since it's a madlib, I have like 10 variables and that would be a lot of work. I can do it of course but if there is a shortcut I'm down for that.

Comment: @ErinMcKee I put my code in a function so you can pass the input to it and get the article.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I implemented the rules from the linked article, do you think that this is accurate enough?

Comment: @TheShadow75 thank you for your help! I was able to break it down and figure out which each thing did. Is this “calling a function”?

Comment: @ErinMcKee glad I could help! And yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

"An umbrella", but "a user".  Unfortunately, English uses the first sound, not the first letter, to determine whether to use "an" or "a".

In some dialects, you even distinguish between "a history" but "an historian" because accented "h" is treated differently than an unaccented one.

If you check to see if the lower-cased first letter is an "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u", you'll probably get about 95% accuracy.  Beyond that is a lot of hard work.

Comment: How would you type that into the code? I'll take the 95% accuracy happily.

Comment: See the other answer.